# Cordova whitelist plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

My app works fine on the browser but not on the device: 
The ionic app only loads the HTML and CSS but does not load the http requests and run the JS.

In Xcode it's stuck at this point:

```
2016-06-18 11:43:59.169 waettr[719:414729] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.1.0 is starting.
2016-06-18 11:43:59.170 waettr[719:414729] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2016-06-18 11:43:59.203 waettr[719:414729] Using UIWebView
2016-06-18 11:43:59.204 waettr[719:414729] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.057995ms
2016-06-18 11:43:59.205 waettr[719:414729] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.080990ms
2016-06-18 11:43:59.205 waettr[719:414729] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.043035ms
2016-06-18 11:43:59.217 waettr[719:414729] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 12.061000ms
2016-06-18 11:43:59.224 waettr[719:414729] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 6.388009ms
2016-06-18 11:43:59.224 waettr[719:414729] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.630975ms
2016-06-18 11:43:59.225 waettr[719:414729] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 20.883977ms
2016-06-18 11:43:59.366 waettr[719:414729] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-06-18 11:44:01.708 waettr[719:414729] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/8365EFD8-1FAA-4E82-8DB6-2ADCD8E53A90/waettr.app/www/index.html#/home
```

I have the following settings:

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://maps.googleapis.com/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://api.openweathermap.org/*"/>
```

This Tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' maps.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

What's my mistake? I'm getting headaches from this...

Comment: if you post more detailed logs, it would be useful. Is there a <access origin="*" />  in you config file?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Are you getting any 401, access denied errors or something like that?

Comment: No, there is no network activity. When I refresh there is network activity but not everything. No 40x errors

Comment: Check in mobile browser. Are those API endpoints returning response in iPhone safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making Ajax calls to:

```
 <allow-navigation href="https://maps.googleapis.com/*"/>
 <allow-navigation href="http://api.openweathermap.org/*"/>
```

which I guess is why you have those in your config.xml, then I recommend that you update your Content Security Policy meta tab to include a connect-src declaration.  This defines where you can make Ajax calls to.

Try setting the following Content Security Policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' maps.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src https://maps.googleapis.com http://api.openweathermap.org">
```

Here I added connect-src and the URLs that I think you are trying to make Ajax requests to.  If you'd like more information on this, here's a [relevant blog post](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).